# Delete selected record in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to deleted the selected record.

Here is my code:

```
echo '<td>';
echo $sqlUitlezenAccountsRank.'<br>';
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo '<form method="post">
    <input name="AccountEdit" value ="Bewerken" type="submit">
</form>'.'<br>';
echo '</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo '<form method="post">
<input name="AccountDelete" value ="Verwijderen" type="submit">
</form>'.'<br>';
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';

if (isset($_POST['AccountDelete'])) {
    $DeleteAccount = "DELETE FROM StaffLeden WHERE GebruikersID=".$sqlUitlezenAccountsEach['GebruikersID'];

if ($conn->query($DeleteAccount) === TRUE) {
    echo "Account succesvol verwijderd";
} else {
    echo "Fout bij het verwijderen van het account: " . $conn->error;
}
```

But if I click delete `Verwijderen` it deletes all data from the mysql table and it shows multiple times `'Account succesvol verwijderd'`*(Succesfully deleted the account)* But I want that it only deletes the one where you click delete `Verwijderen`

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: print out the Statement and see what is generated

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['AccountDelete'])`  will be either be true or false in **all** iterations of the loop leading to deletion of everything.  You need a way to find which account id you need to delete.

Comment: And how do i do that?

Comment: PHP and SQL are different languages. MySQL can't even see your PHP code. What counts is the actual SQL code, in this case stored in the `$DeleteAccount` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by adding the id to the forms, check the hidden ids, and the the POST in the query

```
                    echo '<td>';
                            echo $sqlUitlezenAccountsRank.'<br>';
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '<td>';
                            echo '
                            <form method="post">
                                <input name="GebruikersID" value ="'.$sqlUitlezenAccountsEach['GebruikersID'].'" type="hidden">
                                <input name="AccountEdit" value ="Bewerken" type="submit">
                            </form>
                            '.'<br>';
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '<td>';
                            echo '
                            <form method="post">
                                <input name="GebruikersID" value ="'.$sqlUitlezenAccountsEach['GebruikersID'].'" type="hidden">
                                <input name="AccountDelete" value ="Verwijderen" type="submit">
                            </form>
                            '.'<br>';
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';

                            if (isset($_POST['AccountDelete'])) {
                                $DeleteAccount = "DELETE FROM StaffLeden WHERE GebruikersID=".$_POST['GebruikersID'];

                                if ($conn->query($DeleteAccount) === TRUE) {
                                    echo "Account succesvol verwijderd";
                                } else {
                                    echo "Fout bij het verwijderen van het account: " . $conn->error;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You aren't allowing the page, when posting back, to specify the account to be deleted. You need a hidden field inside the "delete" form which holds the account ID. Then you access this via the $_POST array and use it in your query (which, btw, should urgently be parameterised to better protect you from SQL injection attacks).

2) Clearly this code is inside some kind of loop. Therefore, your DELETE statement will run once every time the loop iterates, which presumably is once for every account in your database. The code which renders the HTML (the loop) and the code which deals with postbacks should be in separate sections of the scripts. They are intended to execute in separate processes (initial request to render HTML, then postback request to deal with the form submission) and should absolutely **not** be lumped in together. In this case it has resulted in an entirely avoidable logic error. In some more MVC- or API-oriented site designs, the two bits of code might even be in separate scripts altogether.